# server specifications needed to create private proxy

Tags: proxy, webserver

I am planning to setup my own personal anonymous forward proxy server. The first thing needed is a web server. I am a bit confused of the specs the server needs. What are the specifications a web server needs to have in order to be become proxy server? Will shared hosting work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost anything* can be used as a proxy server. That 10 year old computer, that ransom Rasberry Pi you bought but never knew what to do with, your phone....

*There are some basic things that the computer will need to have

- Some way to connect to the internet (preferably Ethernet)
- Comparability with the proxy software that your trying to run.

  - Most likely x86 with at least 1 core and 512mb RAM
- Enough space to store the software 10GB will probably do...

Obviously the faster the computer is the more connections it will be able to deal with at the same time and might be able to respond slightly faster.

Digital Ocean have a nice guide on [how to setup a server using one of their virtual servers using SOCKS](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-route-web-traffic-securely-without-a-vpn-using-a-socks-tunnel) (a proxy package). You could check that out and apply it to the shared hosting server that you have access to already.

Comment: Thank you! Small subquestion. If I use shared hosting, than my web server shares it's IP with hundreds of other websites and differs only in PORT. Wouldn't having the same IP as other websites (but different PORT) expose the fact that I must indeed be using a proxy server?